# Excel, Add $1.00 to XS-XL price and show in XXL price in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with hundreds of prices. Each cell has 2 prices. XS-XL one price. XXL another price. I want to add $1.00 to all the XS-XL prices, show for XXL prices.
So basically, XXL prices will be +$1.00 than XS-XL prices.
I need to change this at a time, in all the hundreds of price cells. Is there an option?

Thank you for your kind help.

[image]

Comment: Two questions. How are the prices formatted in the same cell? For the second question, would a formula work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If the string always comes in the same format, then you can use the standard string formulas like `LEFT`, `LEN`, `FIND`, etc. The only thing to be careful of is treating the string that you are adding 1 to as a number by using something like `NUMBERVALUE`.

For example:

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("XXL", A2)-1)&"XXL-$"&
NUMBERVALUE(MID(A2,FIND("$", A2)+1,FIND(".", A2)-FIND("$", A2))&MID(A2, FIND(".", A2)+1,2))+1
```

If you have the newest version of Excel, you can make it look a lot cleaner and avoid repetition by using the `LET` function to name variables.

[image]